# Problemas con dropdownList de html a HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

estoy trabajando en ASP MVC en un crud con filtros de busqueda,el actual que tengo:

```
<span>Producto: </span><input type="text" name="producto" />
```

pero quiero volverlo un dropdownlist intente con htmlHelper:

```
@Html.DropDownList("producto",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.NombreDelProducto,"--PRODUCTOS --")
```

Y me da el siguiente error

> 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'producto'.

Controlador:

```
 PharmcomEntities db = new PharmcomEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PharmcomEntities myentity = new PharmcomEntities();
        var getItem = myentity.Betances.ToList();
        SelectList list = new SelectList(getItem, "ID", "NombreDelProducto");
        ViewBag.NombreDelProducto = list;
        return View(db.Betances.ToList());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DateTime start, DateTime end, int cliente, string producto)
    {
        return View(db.pBetancesExample(start, end, cliente, producto));
    }
```

Vista:

```
  <center>
    <h1>Filtro de fecha</h1>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "pBetances", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <span>Start date: </span><input type="date" name="start" />
        <span>End Date: </span><input type="date" name="end" />
        <span>Cliente: </span><input type="text" name="cliente" />
        @*<span>Producto: </span><input type="text" name="producto" />*@
        @Html.DropDownList("producto",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.NombreDelProducto,"-- PRODUCTOS --") 
        <input type="submit" value="generar filtros" />
    }
</center>
```